# For the following class of matrices, are the determinants invariant under permutations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, asymptotics, determinants, expectation

I want to ask a question regarding the invariance of determinants under permutation. The following matrix is the one I want to discuss here. (It's just a symmetric block tridiagonal matrix with non-zero elements at corners.)
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\Gamma_{1,1} \cdot \mathcal{I}  & \Gamma_{1,2} \cdot P_{1}   & 0   & \underline{0}   & \Gamma_{1,m} \cdot P_{m} \\
\hline
\Gamma_{1,2} \cdot P_{1}^{T}  & \Gamma_{2,2} \cdot \mathcal{I}  & \Gamma_{2,3} \cdot P_{2} & \underline{0}  & 0 \\
\hline
0   & \Gamma_{2,3} \cdot P_{2}^{T}   & \Gamma_{3,3}\cdot \mathcal{I}  & \Gamma_{3,4} \cdot P_{3}  & \underline{0} \\ 
\hline
\underline{0}^{T}   & \ddots    & \ddots   & \ddots  & \ddots \\ 
\hline
\Gamma_{1,m} \cdot P_{m}^{T}  &  0   & 0   & \cdots   & \Gamma_{m,m}\cdot \mathcal{I}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\{P_{i}\}_{i=1}^{m}$ are the permutation matrices with size $M \times M$.

I was trying to prove it by using "Newton's identities" that can connect the determinant with the traces of the n-th power of the matrix. Showing that the diagonal blocks of the $n$th power of this matrix are always identity matrices up to some factors gives us the result.

I didn't find a systematic way to show that the $n$th power of the above matrix has the same diagonal blocks. Or was my intuition wrong?

In this problem, we have two parameters: the size of the base matrix $m$ and the size of permutation matrices $M$. (Perhaps the invariance can be established in some region $(m, M)$.）

(Sorry for the repeated question since I have not enough reputation to give any comments on relevant questions. see also [For the following class of matrices, are the determinants invariant under permutations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3995412/472861) on MSE.)

Based on Lemma 1 in [Molinari - Determinants of block tridiagonal matrices](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0681), I can easily come up with this result by forcing $\bigl(\prod\limits_{i=1}^{m-1} P_{i}\bigr) \cdot P_{m}^{T}  = \mathcal{I}$ (i.e., $P_{m} = \prod\limits_{i=1}^{m-1} P_{i}$). (Maybe it can also come up with the result without such a constraint.)

The determinant will be equivalent to the determinant of the matrix with the following form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
t_1 \cdot \mathcal{I}- h \cdot \bigl(\prod\limits_{i=1}^{m-1}P_{i}\bigr)\cdot P_{m}^{T} & t_2 \cdot P_{m} \\
t_3 \cdot \bigl(\prod\limits_{i=1}^{m-1}P_{i}\bigr)^{\mathrm T} & t_4 \cdot \bigl(\prod\limits_{i=1}^{m-1}P_{i}\bigr)^{T}\cdot P_{m} - \mathcal{I}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Trivially, we can get its invariance under permutations with the constraint that $\bigl(\prod\limits_{i=1}^{m-1} P_{i}\bigr) \cdot P_{m}^{T} = \mathcal{I}$.

Given $\{P_{i}\}_{i=1}^{m-1}$ (say, $P_{i} = \mathcal{I}$, $\forall i \in [m-1]$), if we can prove that their determinants will be unchanged if we consider different $P_{m}$, then we can conclude that determinants are invariant under permutations.

In the above situation, the determinant can be written as $\det((t_1\cdot t_4 - t_2 \cdot t_3) \cdot P_m - h\cdot P_m^{T} - (t_1+h\cdot t_4)\cdot \mathcal{I}$), which, I think, is dependent on $P_m$. Therefore, the statement is not true for all permutations (?).

It seems that the determinant can be eventually reduced to be in the following form: $\det(\ell_{1}\cdot \mathcal{I} + \ell_{2}\cdot W + \ell_{3} \cdot W^{T})$,
denoted by $D(W)$, where $W$ is an arbitrary permuation matrix with size $M \times M$. When $W = \mathcal{I}$, we denote the determinant as $D_{\mathrm{id}}$. Based on this observation, we can reduce the number of possible determinants from $\left(M!\right)^{m}$ to $M!$ and we can conduct numerical simulations for $M < 10$. The simulation result shows that the average of $D(W)$ with respect to $W$, denoted by $\langle D(W)\rangle$, are equal to $D_{\mathrm{id}}$ for $M < 10$.

Equivalently, is there any nice way to discuss the following class of matrices:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\Gamma_{1,1} \cdot \mathcal{I}  & \Gamma_{1,2} \cdot \mathcal{I}   & 0   & \underline{0}   & \Gamma_{1,m} \cdot P_{m} \\
\hline
\Gamma_{1,2} \cdot \mathcal{I}  & \Gamma_{2,2} \cdot \mathcal{I}  & \Gamma_{2,3} \mathcal{I} & \underline{0}  & 0 \\
\hline
0   & \Gamma_{2,3} \cdot \mathcal{I}   & \Gamma_{3,3}\cdot \mathcal{I}  & \Gamma_{3,4} \cdot \mathcal{I}  & \underline{0} \\ 
\hline
\underline{0}^{T}   & \ddots    & \ddots   & \ddots  & \ddots \\ 
\hline
\Gamma_{1,m} \cdot P_{m}^{T}  &  0   & 0   & \cdots   & \Gamma_{m,m}\cdot \mathcal{I}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $P_{m}$ is an arbitrary permutation matrix with size $M \times M$.

Comment: I took the liberty of tweaking your title since sometimes an imperative tone "prove or disprove it" is perceived by those reading in haste as being some kind of assigned exercise or problem-from-a-book. I hope you don't mind the rewording.

Comment: TeX note: use $\langle D(W)\rangle$ `\langle D(W)\rangle` rather than $<D(W)>$ `<D(W)>`.  I have edited accordingly.  Also, you define $\langle D(W)\rangle$ only in the paragraph following the one in which you first use it.